# Official Arduino code: Web Client example doesn't work for me

Tags: arduino, webclient

I am trying to implement the official Arduino Web Client code from examples
which is resided here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient ,
but unfortunately it doesn't work form me.

What am I supposed to do after uploading this sketch???
This is the only line that I changed to:

```
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 178);
```

What I do is going to the url:
192.168.1.178 (in my local network, other sketches work fine in this ip) and if I well understood the function of this code, we request a particular page from google's server, so the server responses and bring to us this page, via the get request we make inside our code. Unfortunately, it doesn't load any page.

If I am wrong to anything of what I've said, please let me know.

Comment: Could someone make it clear to me?

Answer (score 0):

Is your ethernet controller wired perfectly?

> The Ethernet shield allows you to connect a WizNet Ethernet controller to the Arduino or Genuino boards via the SPI bus. It uses pins 10, 11, 12, and 13 for the SPI connection to the WizNet. Later models of the Ethernet shield also have an SD Card on board. Digital pin 4 is used to control the slave select pin on the SD card.

For help, here is the schematic of the shield: [Schematics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaE1N.png)

Watch your serial. Does it say this?

> Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP

Or does it say this?

> connecting...

Does your router use 192.168.1 instead of 192.168.0 or 192.168.2?

Is there any other device who has the same IP address?

If nothing works, try to replace this piece of code

```
// start the Ethernet connection:
if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
}
```

With this

```
// start the Ethernet connection:
if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    if(Ethernet.begin(mac, ip) == 0) {
        Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using IP address. 
        Circuit hanged.");
        while(1){}
    }
}
```

If this code sais:

> Failed to configure Ethernet using IP address. Circuit hanged.

Of course, if you are using a WiFi shield, this example won't work. Try the wifi shield's example which is included in it's library.